# Firebase Sendgrid - unable to send email

Tags: firebase, email, sendgrid

I want to use Firebase+Sendgrid in order to send e-mail after user registers on my website.
The flow is simple:

Using [Firebase send email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email), on every account creation, I'm adding new document to `users` collection.

```
      setDoc(newUserRef, {
        to: user.email,
        message: {
          subject: "Hello!",
          text: "test",
          html: "Test <b>Test</b> <i>Test</i>",
        },
      });
```

This works as intended, since this document is being added to the collection.

However, when i check firestore object, `delivery` object has

```
 state: ERROR,
 error: Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password}
```

At sendgrids end, I've created API Key, verified sender email, and used that api key while installing "trigger email" firebase extension.

I've set trigger email extension like this:

SMTP Connection URI: smtps://`apikey`@smtp.sendgrid.net:465

SMTP password (Optional): `apikey`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When using SMTP with SendGrid, your username is the literal string `apikey` and the password is your API key.

So, your trigger email extension settings should be:

SMTP Connection URI: `smtps://apikey@smtp.sendgrid.net:465`

SMTP password (Optional): `YOUR_API_KEY`